# How to set column width when creating a table in vbscript or javascript?

Tags: lotus-notes

I tried applying the AppendTable method as described in [this article](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_APPENDTABLE_METHOD_RTITEM.html)
for the IBM Lotus Domino Designer.

While i have successfully created the table with fixed width,
I cannot manage to pass the array of paragraph styles to the AppendTable function,
that then does nothing.

I can create a fixed-width table with 5 columns, but this doesn't work for 2 columns, and without returning any error message (only the 5-column table gets drawn in the email).

Any way to fix this issue?

**Existing code (vbscript):**

```
Dim NPGst()
Redim NPGst(2)

Set NPGst(0) = NotesSessions.createRichTextParagraphStyle
NPGst(0).FirstLineLeftMargin = 10
NPGst(0).LeftMargin = 10
NPGst(0).RightMargin = 1000

Set NPGst(1) = NotesSessions.createRichTextParagraphStyle
NPGst(1).FirstLineLeftMargin = 10
NPGst(1).LeftMargin = 10
NPGst(1).RightMargin = 1000

Call NotesRTItem.AppendTable (3,2,,1440,NPGst)
Call NotesRTItem.AppendTable (3,5,,1440)

Call NotesRTItem.update
```

Comment: not quite sure if that is some form of vbscripts array of variants differ from array of objects issues, but i don't remember those obscure information entirely. any hints would be welcome

Comment: I think you are more likely to get an answer in stackoverflow.

Comment: i don't think so... the atmosphere here is more free and open, while i saw stackoverflow is somehow more confine and technoocult.

Comment: @AntonyLee stackoverflow is right place because you have trouble with code. I believe there are people who will help.

Comment: @AntonyLee You mention to make table for email: you have few more options - use MIME format, use RenderToRTItem with predefined table in special form, or use MIDAS LSX extension.

Comment: unfortunately, RenderToRTItem would render into a picture. see if i can get the MIME things work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Lotus, but I do remark that you don't pass the NPGst array to the function
call that creates the five columns. Maybe that's why it works ? ;)

I tried to compare your code with that found in [this example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLES_APPENDTABLE_METHOD_RTITEM.html),
and I remark that the code there looks different.
Applying the example code to your code gives this :

```
Dim styles(1 To 2) As NotesRichTextParagraphStyle

For i% = 1 To 2 Step 1
  Set styles(i%) = session.CreateRichTextParagraphStyle
  styles(i%).LeftMargin = 10
  styles(i%).FirstLineLeftMargin = 10
  styles(i%).RightMargin = 1000
Next

Call body.AppendTable (3, 5,, 1440, styles)
```

Comment: that is visual basic code instead of visual basic script, which require compile to an EXE. while i can only use script base language, either vbscript or javascript due to security limitation. (idea: to let the auditor know what you are doing, "do they really can read it ?")

Comment: but yes, i believe that it worth to try array of 1 TO 2 instead of 0 to 1, i will post after i make the test.

Comment: use array 1 to 2 have return an error of object missing for the styles field

Comment: guess i should try method this link, to put the tables as HTML may be easier. http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Lotus-Notes-email-via-vbscript-m44819.aspx